# Java, store method reference for later execution

Tags: java

In java 8, I would like to store method reference.

The context is: my program may not be able to execute methods right now but must execute them before it terminates. So my objective is to store these methods in a dedicated class that will execute them before program terminates.

So far, here is what I tried:

I have an interface that matches what the method prototype should be:

```
public interface IExecutable {
    public void method(String[] args);
}
```

I have a class that is supposed to store methods and their arguments:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LateExecutor {

    private Map<String[], IExecutable> tasks = new HashMap<>();

    public void execute() {
        tasks.forEach((args, method) -> method(args));
    }

    public void storeTask(String[] args, IExecutable method) {
        tasks.put(args, method);
    }
}
```

With this, I wanted to call `storeTask` with something like this, from another class:

```
lateExecutor.storeTask(arrayOfArgs, object::method)
```

But with the current state of the `LateExecutor` class, I have the following error on `-> method(`:

> The method method(String[]) is undefined for the type LateExecutor

Which I understand because LateExecutor does not have this method.

However that leaves me with the following problem: **How to store method reference and execute them later** (Any other idea to solve my problem is also welcomed).

Comment: I suppose for the `object::method` syntax to work you need to annotate your `IExecutable` interface with `@FunctionalInterface`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map has instances of `IExecutable`s, and that's how you should treat them:

```
public void execute() {
    //better rename "method" to something like "executable"
    tasks.forEach((args, method) -> method.method(args));
}
```

The `method` parameter in the `forEach` lambda expression is an `IExecutable`, and the name of the method in that interface is `method`.

---

*Side note*: you shouldn't need to declare `IExecutable`. There's a built-in functional interface with that method signature: you can use `Consumer<String[]>` (then `accept(args)` would be how you invoke the method)

Comment: This signature was for test only. My actual methods have several parameters.  Is the Consumer<String[]> the only one available ?

Comment: Re: "Side note". You don't *need to*, but there are often compelling reasons to do so anyway. Often, declaring your own interface adds semantic value where something like `BiFunction<String, Integer, Boolean>` is pretty meaningless. Agree that in this case `IExecutable` is not adding much value, though I tend to avoid using arrays in generic type parameters because they don't interact in a way that most people find intuitive.

Comment: `String[]` is just the type argument from your example. Yo can find a bunch of built-in functions; check the [`java.util.function` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

`method` is the name of the `IExecutable` so you'd need to do `method.method(args)`

```
public void execute() {
    tasks.forEach((args, method) -> method.method(args));
}
```